# Audio loop attribute works not on every mp3 file and has a little pypt sound at the end

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

Somehow, the `loop` attribute doesn't work on every .mp3 file and I don't understand why. It also has a little strange sound similar to "pypt" and the end. JS looping works the same. You can listen to this in the demo.

I'm creating a Simon game and there are 4 links to these sounds:

1. https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3
2. https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3
3. https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3
4. https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3

Every one of them has a little "pypt" in the end and I was trying to search for an answer to this problem so  found this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/edmproduction/comments/3rp309/fl_studio_12_slight_popping_at_the_start_and_end/):

> Its to do with the phasing at the at the start of the sample. If you take the sound wave to a point where it's at the axis, i.e. no sound, then you won't get it. The popping is (for example) when you end a sound abruptly when the woofer is still "poking out" so to say, and the pop is made when it jumps back to silence.

Yes, I tried to use a program which could make the "fade out" effect and it worked, however, it's not for my case because **I have to loop without any sound volume changed**.

So, the "fade out" effect is out. What can I do then?

```html
<audio id="music" autoplay loop>
  <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<!-- https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3 - LOOPS ONLY ONCE -->
<!-- https://s1.vocaroo.com/media/download_temp/Vocaroo_s1WvOFSeks6I.mp3 - LOOPS FOREVER -->
```

Comment: Why would you loop any sound for Simon game? Every sequence of sound is a short burst. The *pypht* sound is when sound is cut off above or below 0 amplitude. Crossfading is a way to smoothly reach 0.

Comment: Because until the user releases his mouse, it should loop forever.

Comment: User would never leave their mouse on a Simon Says game because 75% time the next sound will be a different color.

Comment: Go [here](http://www.kellyking.me/projects/simon/) and keep the mousedown on a color. Look at the source, there are no audio loops.